# What is the best way to store unique data for tile types?

Tags: c++, world-editor, raylib

To store specific data unique to each tile type, what is the best way to do this?

Say a tile has an ID corresponding to data concerning its name, block strength, texture, health, etc; how could this be done? I am considering using parallel arrays to store this data, but would like to know if there are other solutions.

Comment: What problem do you foresee with the approach you've thought of so far? In what specific ways should answers aim to provide a "better" solution?

Comment: The broad options are either parallel arrays for each aspect or to use a data type (class, struct, etc) to hold all the aspect data for each tile type. There are pros & cons to each solution. "Best" is almost always context specific.

Comment: use the approach that it's easiest to implement. if you hit a bottleneck, only then you should consider switching to a different implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 vectors; one to store the info and another as the tilemap just storing ids:

```
using TileID = unsigned int;
std::vector<TileID> tile_map {};

struct TileInfo {
  TileID id {};
  std::string name {};
  int strength {};
  Sprite sprite {};
  // etc...
};

std::vector<TileInfo> tiles_info {};
// put your tiles' id like:
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < DIFFERENT_KINDS_OF_TILES; ++i) {
  TileInfo current_tile_info {};
  current_tile.id = i;
  // the rest of the tile info should be manually added somewhere else
  tiles_info.push_back(current_tile_info);
}

// so you can do something like:
for (const auto& tile: tile_map) {
  draw(tiles_info[tile].sprite);
}
```

As said in the comments before, it's not the **best** method, just another way to do it.